# ImportError: cannot import name RemovedInDjango19Warning after Django upgrade

Tags: django, python-2.7

I was using Django 1.8 and I wanted to upgrade to the latest version (1.11.6). When I did that I got this error message when trying to run the development server:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango19Warning
ImportError: cannot import name RemovedInDjango19Warning
```

I can uninstall django and run pip install django=1.9 but I want to keep the latest version. Any tip of how to solve that? Thanks!

PS: I'm running python 2.7.13

Comment: Why do you need to import a `RemovedInDjango19Warning` if you're using Django 1.11? Any time you would need to use that error, won't you get an error from python about the imported thing not being there, etc?

Comment: I dont need that import, I don't even know where it came from. From the trace it looks like it's coming from .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 6, in <module>

Comment: are you using some third-party packages? Maybe the import error resides in one of them.

Comment: I am not using any app besides the apps I created myself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in python 2.7.
Reinstalling Python 2.7 solved the issue.

How did I came up with the solution?
I tried `python3 manage.py runserver` instead of `python manage.py runserver` and the server worked (but with problems of course since I was using `print x` instead of `print(x)` So I knew there was something up with python not django.